# TransBase, Select all tables containing a given column

Tags: transbase

I need to query statement to list all tables from a database containing a given column name
in TransBase.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

select * from syscolumn col 
inner join systable tbl on tbl.segno=col.tsegno
where col.cname like '%col_name%';

That was quick! For everybody that might need this in future.